# Matplotlib: Replace scatterplot axes by boxplot

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a scatterplot in which the axes are narrow boxplots of the marginal distribution. I see one way to achieve this by having multiple subplot axes with shared x/y axis, but I would prefer a solution that achieves this in a single axes/subplot. In principle, this could be achieved like this:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.boxplot(x, vert=False, positions=[ypos], widths=ywidth)
plt.boxplot(y, vert=True, positions=[xpos], widths=xwidth)

ax = plt.gca()
q = 25, 50, 75
plt.setp(ax, frame_on=False, xticks=np.percentile(x, q), yticks=np.percentile(y, q))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

Where I could take:

```
ypos = y.min()
ywidth = 0.01*y.ptp()
xpos = x.min()
xwidth = 0.01*x.ptp()
```

However, if I change the axes limits, this will move the scatter plots with the data rather than keeping them in a fixed position relative to the axes. Is there a better way to achieve this? Is it possible to replace the spines by boxplots?

Comment: Did you consider [seaborn](https://python-graph-gallery.com/82-marginal-plot-with-seaborn/)?

Comment: I didn't really. `seaborn.jointplot` goes in the right direction, but uses a histogram (or KDE) where I would like a boxplot. Also, I'd prefer a pure matplotlib solution. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: [This example](https://python-graph-gallery.com/24-histogram-with-a-boxplot-on-top-seaborn/) does a marginal boxplot, though only in one direction. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to 2D.

Comment: Thank you, that's basically the solution that I meant by "shared x/y axis". But I like the example page in general.